How to play animations from a .glb file with sceneform?
I'm developing an AR virtual pet application using Sceneform and ArCore in Java in Android Studio and I have a .glb model with multiple animations. In the end, I want ot make something like Pokemon Go. Currently, my code renders the model, but I can't figure out how to play the animations one after the other. Specifically, I want to play the "Congratulate" animation first, followed by the "Approach" animation.
Here's my code:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.ar.core.Anchor;
import com.google.ar.core.HitResult;
import com.google.ar.core.Plane;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.AnchorNode;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.ModelRenderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Renderable;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.ArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.BaseArFragment;
import com.google.ar.sceneform.ux.TransformableNode;
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArFragment arCam; //object of ArFragment Class

    private int clickNo = 0; //helps to render the 3d model only once when we tap the screen

    public static boolean checkSystemSupport(Activity activity) {

        //checking whether the API version of the running Android >= 24 that means Android Nougat 7.0
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            String openGlVersion = ((ActivityManager) Objects.requireNonNull(activity.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))).getDeviceConfigurationInfo().getGlEsVersion();

            //checking whether the OpenGL version >= 3.0
            if (Double.parseDouble(openGlVersion) >= 3.0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "App needs OpenGl Version 3.0 or later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                activity.finish();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "App does not support required Build Version", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            activity.finish();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (checkSystemSupport(this)) {

            arCam = (ArFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arCameraArea);
            //ArFragment is linked up with its respective id used in the activity_main.xml

            arCam.setOnTapArPlaneListener((hitResult, plane, motionEvent) -> {
                clickNo++;
                //the 3d model comes to the scene only when clickNo is one that means once
                if (clickNo == 1) {

                    Anchor anchor = hitResult.createAnchor();
                    ModelRenderable.builder()
                            .setSource(this, R.raw.hund)
                            .setIsFilamentGltf(true)
                            .build()
                            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addModel(anchor, modelRenderable))
                            .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                                builder.setMessage("Somthing is not right" + throwable.getMessage()).show();
                                return null;
                            });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void addModel(Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable modelRenderable) {

        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        // Creating a AnchorNode with a specific anchor
        anchorNode.setParent(arCam.getArSceneView().getScene());
        //attaching the anchorNode with the ArFragment
        TransformableNode model = new TransformableNode(arCam.getTransformationSystem());
        model.setParent(anchorNode);
        //attaching the anchorNode with the TransformableNode
        model.setRenderable(modelRenderable);
        //attaching the 3d model with the TransformableNode that is already attached with the node
        model.select();
    }

How can I access and play specific animations from my .glb model?
I would greatly appreciate any code snippets or resources that could help me implement this functionality. Thanks in advance!

To sequentially play multiple glb animations in ARCore/Sceneform app use the following code:
AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();

animatorSet.playSequentially(
    ModelAnimator.ofMultipleAnimations(character, "idle", "jog", "fall")
);
animatorSet.start();


This is a link to a web resource where you can read more about this and see how it's implemented with examples.
